Cannot invoke "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLCollation.writeCollation(com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter)" because "collation" is null
I'm currently writing a SQL proxy for a SQL Server database. The idea is for my proxy to receive client requests (in this case from DBeaver), parse those TDS packets, execute the SQL query using pyodbc, and reconstruct a valid TDS packet to send the result back to the client.
I'm avoiding SSL handshakes for now and using pyodbc to connect directly to the SQL Server.
Use Case

The client sends a packet to my proxy.

The proxy parses the packet, determines if it's an SQL batch (e.g., a SELECT command like SELECT db_name(), schema_name(), original_login();).



The proxy runs the query with pyodbc.

The proxy receives the results and reconstructs a TDS response packet to interpret back to the client.


The Problem
After constructing the packet (see the code below), DBeaver closes the connection with the error message:

Cannot invoke "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLCollation.writeCollation(com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter)" because "collation" is null

I've constructed the packet to include:

Column Metadata for the columns returned by the query.
Row Data for the values of each column.
Done Token
according to Microsoft Specification

Below is my code for constructing the response packet. I would appreciate any insights into what I'm doing wrong in the packet construction.
def construct_tds_response(columns, rows):
     # Step 1: Create Packet Header
    packet_type = 0x04  # Type: Response
    packet_status = 0x01  # Status: End of message
    packet_length = 0x0033  # Length: Placeholder value for now, will be updated later
    header = construct_tds_header(packet_type, packet_status, packet_length)

    # Step 2: Create COLMETADATA (Token Type: 0x81)
    colmetadata_token = pack('<B', 0x81)  # COLMETADATA Token Type
    col_count = pack('<H', len(cursor.description))  # Number of columns

    colmetadata = colmetadata_token + col_count

    # Add metadata for each column
    for col in cursor.description:
        col_name = col[0]
        user_type = pack('<L', 0x00000000)  # UserType (0)
        flags = pack('<H', 0x0020)  # Flags (Nullable)
        col_type = pack('<B', 0xA7)  # Data Type (NVARCHAR)
        col_max_length = pack('<H', 0x1F40)  # Max Length (8000)
        # Use a proper collation value; this should be dynamically determined if needed
        collation = bytes([0x09, 0x04, 0xD0, 0x00, 0x34])  # Collation (5 bytes)
        col_name_len = pack('<B', len(col_name))  # Column Name Length
        col_name_encoded = col_name.encode('utf-16le')  # Column Name (UTF-16LE)

        colmetadata += user_type + flags + col_type + col_max_length + collation + col_name_len + col_name_encoded

    # Step 3: Create ROW Data (Token Type: 0xD1)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    row_data = b''
    for row in rows:
        row_token = pack('<B', 0xD1)  # ROW Token Type
        row_content = b''
        for col_value in row:
            if col_value is None:
                row_content += pack('<H', 0xFFFF)  # Null value indicator
            elif isinstance(col_value, str):
                col_data = col_value.encode('utf-16le')
                col_len = len(col_data)  # UTF-16 length in bytes
                row_content += pack('<H', col_len) + col_data
            else:
                col_data = str(col_value).encode('utf-16le')
                col_len = len(col_data)
                row_content += pack('<H', col_len) + col_data

        row_data += row_token + row_content
    # Step 4: Create DONE Token (Token Type: 0xFD)
    done_token = pack('<B', 0xFD)  # DONE Token Type
    done_status = pack('<H', 0x0010)  # DONE Status
    cur_cmd = pack('<H', 0x00C1)  # Current Command
    done_row_count = pack('<Q', len(rows))  # Row count

    done = done_token + done_status + cur_cmd + done_row_count

    # Combine all parts to form the complete packet
    tds_data = colmetadata + row_data + done

    # Update packet length
    packet_length = len(tds_data) + 8  # Header length is always 8 bytes
    header = construct_tds_header(packet_type, packet_status, packet_length)

    # Combine header and data to form the final TDS packet
    tds_packet = header + tds_data

    return tds_packet


The constructed TDS packet
b'\x04\x01\x00E\x00\x00\x01\x00\x81\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\xa7@\x1f\t\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\xa7@\x1f\t\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\xa7@\x1f\t\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\x10\x00\xc1\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
Question
What am I doing wrong in constructing the TDS response packet? I can't see the SQL result in the packet too?
Note: the packet construction is currently only for this specific use case. I plan to extend it for handling different types of SQL commands and data types once I get this to work.
Any guidance or corrections would be highly appreciated. I'm a beginner, and constructing this packet is still very complicated for me, and not enough resources to help

I wouldn't say that writing proxy for sql server is a good beginner task, why in the world would you want to do this? But anyway, when I did this stuff, I used Wireshark to run real code and then tried to replicate the payloads. Note that there are subtle differences in tds versions when it comes to packet contents. I used sql server Java driver source code to compare what I was doing, which also made things somewhat easier. Also note that this stuff probably won't work with latest tds which uses ssl from the beginning

Okay, thank you. Let me try another method
